# href contains php variable in it not opening correct location

Tags: php, html

I have the following `<td>` tag with `<a>` tag in it that contains a php variable in href. I only can browse upto uploads folder. Does anyone know why? It supposed to browse until `uploads\$_POST['searchInput']`  . But it is not doing that.

```html
<td class="viewEditTd"><button class = "btn btn-info viewEditButton"><a href="file://///172.xx.xx.xxx\TEMP\xxx\uploads\"<?php echo $_POST['searchInput']; ?>"\" target="_blank"><span class="
        glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> View File</a></button></td>
```

Comment: Why is it marked as duplicate? I think it's genuinely different question. I was about to answer this.

Comment: @Barmer: I don't understand why you mark as duplicate. And when i checked the so called answer you suggested in another post, it is quite different.

Comment: @Barmar ^ that was intended for you. They misspelled your name.

Comment: @Anu Please take care when typing someone's name. Typos do count here also, so I had to ping him myself so he could see the probable error.

Comment: see my [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8HKl.png) @Anu

Comment: @Barmar Please remove the duplicate lock. I saw the answer you suggested is discussing different topics whereas my question is different

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you. i will take note about the typo next time

Comment: @qskane Thanks a lot. Such a silly mistake from me. Your suggestion worked perfectly fine. How to mark your answer as correct?

Comment: @Anu you can't. because this is just a  comment, I think you need an IDE, such as PhpStom , that is why I can easily fix your error :)

Comment: @qskane Thanks. The question is wrongly locked as duplicate by someone. So I can't post your suggested code as answer too.

Comment: @Anu It is not wrongly locked, just because there are too many typos questions. No matter, you should feel happy, the question is solved

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate because I thought you were asking why the `<?php echo $_POST['searchInput']; ?>` is showing up on the page.

Comment: @Anu Typo questions shouldn't get an answer anyway. They should be closed as off-topic, using the reason "Couldn't reproduce or typo".

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for removing the lock. By the way the typo Funk Forty Niner mentioned is not typo in question. It is the typo error I made when i tried to type your name in the comments. There was no typo in my question earlier

Comment: @Anu The typo I was talking about was the extra double quotes around the php tag.

Comment: @Barmar When I posted the question, i was using those double quotes intentionally by thinking, it was needed. Not a typo error from me; that is what i thought. I believe stack overflow got many questions such as this one whereby the person who posted question thought some formatting needed whereby actually such formatting will cause codes to crash. Anyhow, for my case I realized the mistake in my code and I got the correct answer too from here itself

Comment: For our purposes it might as well be a typo. There's no close reason specifically for such minor errors, we use that one for most questions where the error is really minor and the solution is not likely to help future readers. It's good you resolved your issue, this is just about whether it's a useful question for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue with the help of Stack overflow forum member. This is how it solved. My issue was as below

```html
<td class="viewEditTd"><button class = "btn btn-info viewEditButton"><a href="file://///172.xx.xx.xxx\TEMP\xxx\uploads\"<?php echo $_POST['searchInput']; ?>"\" target="_blank"><span class="
        glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> View File</a></button></td>
```

It was solved by removing the two double quotes around the `php` tags. Working answer is

```html
<td class="viewEditTd"><button class = "btn btn-info viewEditButton"><a href="file://///172.xx.xx.xxx\TEMP\xxx\uploads\<?php echo $_POST['searchInput']; ?>" target="_blank"><span class="
        glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> View File</a></button></td>
```